# Dynamic routing in Next Js return 404 and then reloads

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Whenever the user clicks on the button I need to redirect to /solutions/[id] where id is dynamic. Tried using Link and next router. If I click that button its failing for the first time(returns 404) and then automatically page reloads. Is this expected behaviour? How do i avoid this?

```
<Link href="/quiz/solutions/a">
     <a>First comment</a>
</Link>
```

My folder structure

```
pages
    -solutions
          -[index].js
```

Comment: what version of nextjs are you using?

Comment: @kyle  "next": "9.5.1",
            "next-redux-wrapper": "^6.0.2",

Answer (score 1):

On Next versions prior to 10, you have to use the `href` and `as` props. Check out [this issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7892) for more information. [Here is a link](https://nextjs.org/docs/tag/v9.5.2/api-reference/next/link#dynamic-routes) to the old documentation as well, the relevant part of the docs state:

> `href` is a file system path used by the page and it shouldn't change at runtime. `as` on the other hand, will be dynamic most of the time according to your needs.

```
<Link href="/quiz/solutions/[id]" as="/quiz/solutions/a">
  <a>First comment</a>
</Link>
```

This is assuming that the page is `[id].js` inside the solutions folder.